# Same language in stacktrace and script tab in Firebug

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, firebug

After an update, Firebug somehow detects that source script was written in Coffeescript and decompiles it in script tab.
However when script throws an error, line numbers still indicate places in executable Javascript.

It makes me puzzled during debuging a code, because line numbers aren't the same in Javascript and Coffeescript.

Does anybody know a way to turn off the novel feature in Firebug, to make preview language and stacktrace language the same?

Comment: I don't have experience with CoffeeScript, though I guess when you see CoffeeScript within Firebug, you forgot to compile it.

Comment: @SebastianZartner The whole project is hosted on webserver engine that serves only compiled JavaScript -I can see it also in network tab in Firebug that Javascript is returned from server in GET requests issued by browser

Comment: I just found out that it is a common problem in Firebug:
https://github.com/firebug/firebug/issues/7920